# Using regex to pass syntax-valid c++ declaration/initialization (considering their data types)

Tags: javascript, regex

This question is related to this: [Using regex to pass syntax-valid c++ declaration/initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421675/using-regex-to-pass-syntax-valid-c-declaration-initialization) thanks to the answer of **Jerry**.

But now the program flow has been redesigned. It will now check the syntax of the declaration per data type.

```
//found int
if( /+sint$/.test(kword_search)){

    //syntax check
    if( //*modified regex for int declaration checking*//.test(kword_syntax_search) ){
        //no error in int;
    }
}

//found char
if( /+schar$/.test(kword_search)){

    //syntax check
    if( //*modified regex for char declaration checking*//.test(kword_syntax_search) ){
        //no error in char;
    }
}

//found float
if( /+sfloat$/.test(kword_search)){

    //syntax check
    if( //*modified regex for float declaration checking*//.test(kword_syntax_search) ){
        //no error in float;
    }
}

//found bool
if( /+sbool$/.test(kword_search)){

    //syntax check
    if( //*modified regex for bool declaration checking*//.test(kword_syntax_search) ){
        //no error in bool;
    }
}
```

So, basically the previous answer is used as this:

```
//found int|char|bool|float
if( /+s(?:int|float|char|bool)$/.test(kword_search)){

    //syntax check
    if( /^(?:\s*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*(?:=\s*(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[+\/*-][A-Za-z0-9]+)?|[‌​0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?:[+\/*-][0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)?|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'))?\s*,)*\s*[A-Z‌​a-z_][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*(?:=\s*(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[+\/*-][A-Za-z0-9]+)?|[0-9]+(?:\.[0-‌​9]+)?(?:[+\/*-][0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)?|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'))?\s*;/.test(kword_syntax_search) ){
        //no error in declaration/initialization by mixing them;
    }
}
```

I need some help to chop this regex to be in 4 sets of regex dedicated to evaluate an int,char,float and bool in the first block of code (**Jerry**'s answer):

`^(?:\s*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*(?:=\s*(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[+\/*-][A-Za-z0-9]+)?|[‌​0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?:[+\/*-][0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)?|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'))?\s*,)*\s*[A-Z‌​a-z_][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*(?:=\s*(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[+\/*-][A-Za-z0-9]+)?|[0-9]+(?:\.[0-‌​9]+)?(?:[+\/*-][0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)?|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'))?\s*;`http://regex101.com/r/aD2hA6

My goal is to tell this string inputs in my code editor if they are syntactically valid or not

int `a,b,_ab;//valid`

int `a=0,b=333; //valid`

int `a, b=; //not valid`

int `a,,b,,; //not valid`

int `1var; //not valid`

int `a='sts', b=false, c=23.0 // not valid`

float `a,b;//valid`

float `a=2, a=3.33//valid`

float `a='sfsdf';//not valid`

float `a==3;//not valid`

float `a,, b=3.0//not valid`

char `a, b;//valid`

char `a='a', b='!', c='3';//valid`

char `a='ab';//not valid`

char `a,b=3;//not valid`

char `a,b="a";//not valid`

bool `a=true, b=false;`

bool `a="true"; //not valid`

(get the idea?)

Again... I know regex is not the right way of doing this. Thanks

Comment: uh no. I need 4 set of regex dedicated for checking int, char, float and bool. should i edit my question sir? is it vague?

Comment: Ok @Jerry, ill update it again for more detailed examples

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for making sure code is syntactically correct. You will need a parser.

Comment: @bart: im aware, i need to finish this anyway

Comment: @jerry: no, it must not accept double quotes. Yes, true and false only

Comment: @fireflieslive Huh, why is `a='ab';` not valid?

Comment: @jerry: it must be a single character only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the integer one, you could perhaps use this:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*(?:=\s*[0-9]+)?,\s*)*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*(?:=\s*[0-9]+)?;$
```

These will match `a,b;`, `a=0,b=333;` and reject `a, b=;` or `a='sts'` or `b=false, c=23.0`.

For the float, maybe that one:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*(?:=\s*[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)?,\s*)*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*(?:=\s*[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)?;$
```

For the character syntax, I guess:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*(?:=\s*'[^']')?,\s*)*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*(?:=\s*'[^']')?;$
```

And for the boolean one, maybe that:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*(?:=\s*(?:true|false))?,\s*)*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*(?:=\s*(?:true|false))?;$
```

Note: Those were specifically made for the examples you provided. I cannot guarantee that it will work for all the different scenarios you have since I don't have much experience with C++.

EDIT: Adding operators to float and integer regexes:

int

```
^(?:[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*(?:=\s*[0-9]+(?:[+\/*-][0-9]+)?)?,\s*)*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*(?:=\s*[0-9]+(?:[+\/*-][0-9]+)?)?;$
```

float

```
^(?:[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*(?:=\s*[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?:\s*[+\/*-[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)?)?,\s*)*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*(?:=\s*[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?:\s*[+\/*-[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)?)?;$
```

Comment: i forgot to include initialization with declaration, can you update it, just like the your previous answer, that supports operators?

Comment: @fireflieslive I assume there's only `int` and `float` to update? Added them to the answer.