# Why is 'int x = + "foo";' a type error but not a syntax error?

Tags: c++

All compilers I tried correctly reject the code

```
int main() {
  int x = "foo";
}
```

with a type error: `const char[4]` cannot be converted to `int`. Why is it that the same compilers (including [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Mh2Qe4)) give the *same* error for

```
int main() {
  int x = + "foo";
}
```

instead of (as I would have thought) a syntax error becaus of the `+` sign? My first idea was that `const char[4]` decays to a pointer, which in turn is treated as an integral value so the `+` denotes "positive". Seems a little far-fetched though, and I would have expected to see `const char*` appear in the error message.

Comment: http://ideone.com/LYHiH0 changing `x` to `const char*` compiles, so apparently the plus sign isn't a syntax error.  I would be interested to know why though.  As a side note, on my run in ideone the error for your link says that a `const char*` can't be converted to `int`, not `const char[4]`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Syntax doesn't involve types in the type system sense (ints and chars and pointers), only types in the syntactic sense of keywords, operators, expressions. In C++ syntax, `+` is a unary prefix operator that can precede an expression. `"foo"` is an expression. Therefore, `+"foo"` is a valid expression as far as the parser is concerned.

Your idea that the string constant decays into a pointer and `+` is a no-op on pointers is correct, and the following program even compiles and runs:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char *message = +"Hello!\n";
    std::cout << message;
}
```

... but that's irrelevant. What you're seeing is a type error, not a syntax error.

**EDIT** Perhaps even more convincing is the fact that you can overload unary `+`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct SomeType {
    const char *operator+() const
    {
        return "Hello, world!\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    SomeType x;
    std::cout << +x;
}
```

Comment: I somehow assumed that `+` is an unary prefix operator which can precede numeric literals only (i.e. something which is readily detectable at parse time). It didn't occur to me that it can precede any expression!

Comment: @FrerichRaabe You can even overload it, see updated answer :)

Comment: Fun facts include that due to negative or positive sign being general operators and not part of the syntax for literals, with C++ implementation based on two's complements representation of integers it's impossible to express the most negative value of a signed type as a negative literal. E.g., for 16 bit `int`, the expression `-32768` is equivalent to `0 - 32768` which involves the positive value 32768 which is out of range: invalid.

Comment: It's not exactly as @Cheersandhth.-Alf suggests: for 16 bit `int`, the expression `-32768` is the application of the unary `-` operator to the decimal constant `32768`. `32768` cannot fit into an `int`, so it has type `long`, and negating a `long` produces another `long`. `-32768` therefore always has the expected value, just not always the expected type. What *can* produce that problem is the expression `-9223372036854775808`, since `9223372036854775808` might not fit into any signed integer type.

Comment: Syntax does involve types in C++ actually... http://stackoverflow.com/a/14589567/541686

Comment: @hvd: Your explanation that 32768 "cannot fit into an int" is not different from my explanation "is out of range". These expressions mean the same, namely that the value is not one of the possible int values. Oh my a third wording. I think it's nice that you elaborate on this but the "it's not exactly as Alf suggests" is a bit misleading. :-)

Comment: The main problem that makes it necessary to express the most negative value of `int` as `int` is this requirement on `INT_MIN` and friends: "except for `CHAR_BIT` and `MB_LEN_MAX`, the
following shall be replaced by expressions that have the same type as would an expression that is an object of the corresponding type converted according to the integer promotions." (from C99 draft N869 §5.2.4.2.1/1). Which is where I've encountered it. It's funny what sticks in the mind...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I disagree with your conclusion that -32768 is invalid on an implementation with 16-bit ints, and my comment was meant to show that it is valid. But you are right that it would be invalid in the specific context of a definition of `INT_MIN`, which would need something like `(-32767-1)` instead.

Comment: @hvd: oh. to put it that way, it's not a valid 16-bit int specification. in fact the rewrite principle you show is common in `limits.h` implementations.

Answer (score 9):

Unary `+` applies to pointers and it just returns the value of the type and does not perform integral promotions on pointers so the result is a pointer not an integral type, from the draft C++ standard section `5.3.1` *Unary operators*:

> The operand of the unary + operator shall have arithmetic, unscoped
>   enumeration, or pointer type and the result is the value of the
>   argument. Integral promotion is performed on integral or enumeration
>   operands. The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand.

a string literal is an array of const char, from `2.14.5` *String literals*:

> [...]A narrow string literal has type “array of n const char”,[...]

which will decay to pointer in this context.

Answer (score 7):

The unary `+` operator can be applied to pointer types:

> C++11 5.3.1 [expr.unary.op]/7: The operand of the unary + operator shall have arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, or **pointer type** and the result is the value of the argument.

So the literal array is converted to `const char *`, and the operator applied to that pointer, before failing to assign the pointer to an `int` just as in the first example.

Comment: Interestingly, compiling my test program with Visual Studio 2012 yields the error message that `const char[4]` cannot be converted to `int`, i.e. the fact that the pointer decays is not visible in the error message anymore (Ideone.com seems to use a compile which does use `const char*` though).

Answer (score 4):

> Why is 'int x = + “foo”;' a type error but not a syntax error?

Because there is no syntax error. There is a semantic error.

After parsing the statement the compiler determines whether such initialization is posiible. In fact syntaxically  the statement looks like

```
int x = + ( expression );
```

Syntaxically this statement is correct. Moreover the unary plus may be applied to pointers.