# How to search for new style C++11 for loops in an existing codebase

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'm using the RegexBuddy utility, with the regex

```
 ^\s*for\s.*:(?!:).*$
```

Which I would paraphrase as 'search lines with optional leading white-space, the text 'for', a single white space, then the rest of the line containing a colon, but not two colons together'.

Which mostly works, but the two colon exclusion doesn't (they are typically iterator references).

What's the correct regex for this search?

Comment: Maybe `^\s*for\b[^:]*:[^:]*$`?

Comment: What if there is no space between the `for` and the opening parentheses (i.e. something like `for(x:y)`)? What if there is multiple spaces?

Comment: You've already got a working answer from @WiktorStribiżew. But just to explain why your doesn't work - the *first* `:` in your regex can also match the second in your input, making the second `:` of the regex **not** match the character after the second in the input. ` for abc::def` matches (not) `:d`.

Comment: In theory, [can C++ code be parsed with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589346/is-c-context-free-or-context-sensitive)? Can it be partially parsed (e.g. so only `for` loops should be found)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` statement does not have to be preceded by a space, nor is a space required between `for` and the opening brace. But OK, here's my attempt:

`^\s*for\s*\([^)]*[^:]:[^:][^)]*\).*`

---

Note: In general, it is all but impossible to accurately parse C++ code with a regex. You need a stateful parser to filter out nested comments, etc.

Comment: And whats with the literal `()`?

Comment: This is for parsing C++11-style for-loops only (the ones that contain a colon)

Comment: That *may* be correct, but you're making assumptions and ignoring criteria given in the question, like "the text 'for', **a single white space**"

Comment: Your answer is better than @WiktorStribiżew as it picked up the one case that had both a colon and a double colon in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this regex (it works with `grep`, not sure about RegexBuddy):

`^\s*for\s*(.\+[^:]:[^:].\+).*$`

The essential part is in `[^:]:[^:]` which only matches a single colon (not immediately preceded or succeeded by another colon) within an arbitrary text inside a pair of parentheses.

**EDIT** [RustyX's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266599/how-to-search-for-new-style-c11-for-loops-in-an-existing-codebase/39266988#comment65868758_39266988) suggests that a regex that will match *only* range-fors is not possible, because it can always be tricked by the colon of a conditional (?:) operator.

Comment: Would this match `for(int i=0;i<10;i++) a = b ? b : (c + 1);` ?

Comment: @RustyX You are right, it will match the colon of the conditional operator.